# How to get git tag(or branch name) of current repository in golang?

Tags: git, go, cmd, command-line-interface

I am writing a golang command-line tool. One command I want to include is to print the version of my tool. My current solution is to hardcode the version in my code. Is it possible to get the branch or tag name of the current repo in golang? Or are there any other solutions?

Comment: @ThinkGoodly I always found build flags tedious & error prone to do this. Now with go 1.16 & using `embed` gives a cleaner way to add static content to a binary using vanilla `go build`

Comment: @ThinkGoodly good point -  `ReadBuildInfo` I don't believe has git info, though?

Comment: @ThinkGoodly Thank you, that is exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Here is one approach:

```
package main

import (
   "os/exec"
   "strings"
)

func main() {
   c, b := exec.Command("git", "describe", "--tag"), new(strings.Builder)
   c.Stdout = b
   c.Run()
   s := strings.TrimRight(b.String(), "\n")
   println(s == "v1.2.4-4-gcda5811")
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec

Comment: I think the OP is asking how to embed git info statically into the binary at compile time.